# Symmetries of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, symmetry, supersymmetry, yang-mills

I know that in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM there is [superconformal symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconformal_algebra) $su(2,2|4)$.

Does this exhaust all symmetries of this theory?

Or there are some more unobvious symmetries?

Maybe AdS/CFT predict such symmetries?

Answer (score 5):

Besides $SU(2,2|4)$ superconformal symmetry the [${\cal N}=4$ SYM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%3D_4_supersymmetric_Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) also enjoys a [$SU(2,2|4)$ dual superconformal symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1095). Together they generate an infinite-dimensional [Yangian symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangian).

Comment: Does this exhaust all symmetries?

Comment: @Nikita https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2987 - I hope this reference would be useful. At the end of paper they mention, that there can be possibly other symmetries